# Magento 2.4.3-p2 error with rest/V1/customers/me webapi

Tags: magento2, webapi

I upgraded to 2.4.3-p2 from 2.4.3 and I am suddenly getting this error when call the rest/V1/customers/me api: "message": "Internal Error. Details are available in Magento log file. Report ID: webapi-64636c25026c3". The exception log shows this: "main.CRITICAL: Report ID: webapi-64636c25026c3; Message: Notice: Undefined index: input-array-size-limit in vendor/magento/module-webapi/Model/Rest/Config.php on line 129 ". I have compared the codebases and it looks like 2.4.3-p2 introduces a new array index. Any one have any ideas?[image]

Comment: Found the answer:

Go to Stores->Config->Services->WebAPI and modify the "Web Api Input Limits" section, specifically "Input List Limit". Clear the cache and it should work.

You can also add

<data input-array-size-limit="[n]" />

to your own custom module's webapi.xml if you are using a custom webapi endpoint.